# Installing Remmina on Yocto Project

Tags: yocto, remmina

I have a YOCTO image running on ARM based board(ICM 3011). I want to install Remmina (rdp client) on the image. The problem is I don't have apt-get on the image , I don't have any package managers either. I have tried downloading the tar file from [remmina.org](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) but cannot install it as I don't have cmake or make or gcc on the yocto image.

I have tried to run binaries from this site: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=remmina but when i run the binary it gives error "EXEC format error".

Can anyone please show me how to install Remmina on `yocto` (on a arm based processor) without using `apt-get` or `cmake` or building the source as I dont have compilers for that either.

Comment: Don't compile on the board, use a [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) on your PC.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the process? Should I compile it on my ubuntu PC with gcc and then port the binaries to Yocto. What files should I transfer ?